# Structuring the Firestore: Should I make another collection to store the changes that were made?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am using Reactjs and Firestore.

I have this collection of `products`:

The `colorMap` is a `map` then below it are the different colors and their quanty.

[image]

Now, I want to create a list or a history whenever a product is added and whenever the quantity in those colors was added more of it.

Should I add another collection that will store when a product is added or whenever quantities are added in the `color`? I'm also thinking of adding a `createdDate`
Or there any other way I could do this? As much as possible, I won't be using any cloud functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to keep the history of each document is by creating a subcollection under that document (say `history`) and writing a new document with either the complete, old document data there for every update you perform, or a new document with just the old values of the fields that were modified.

While it is convenient to do this from Cloud Functions, as they already get both the previous and the new data for each document write, you can accomplish  the same from client-side code too.

Comment: So for each document of the product, I could create a subcollection called `history` and under those subcollections are the old updates I made? Also, if I'll put a `createdDate` will I also be able to query it by order of the date (e.g. descending order)?

Comment: Yes, creating a subcollection for each document's history is a common approach for this use-case. And yes, you can query on field that you define.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be doing a subcollection for the `history`

Comment: If I'm going to delete a document of the product, will the subcollection also be deleted or is there other way around it where the subcollection would not be deleted?

Comment: That seems like a new question to me. But: deleting a document does not automatically delete data from subcollections under that document. If you want to delete data from subcollections, you'll have to make additional calls for that.